# Criar diretório pasta mapeada PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando criar uma pasta em uma mapeamento de rede mas não estou tendo sucesso

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST["databse"]) && isset($_POST["nomecli"])){

    $database = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/criarbase/'.$_POST["databse"];
    $namecli = $_POST["nomecli"];
    $caminho = 'Z:/Bases/'.$namecli;
    $destino = $caminho.'/'.$namecli.'.zip';


    if(is_dir($caminho)){

        echo 'Pasta existe';
    }else{
        if(mkdir($caminho, 0755, true)){
            print_r(error_get_last());
            if (!copy($database, $destino)) {
                echo "falha ao copiar $database...\n";
            }else{
                echo('Base enviada para servidor');
            }
        }

    }

}
```

?>

se eu troco ele para a pasta local funciona tranquilamente
no inicio achei que poderia ser permissão no servidor para criar a pasta, por ser um win server que esta salvando, mas troquei para uma win 10, e o erro permanece como não encontrado o diretório

Comment: Já tentou ao invés de utilizar o Z: colocar o caminho definitivo sem o mapeamento?

Comment: sim, ele trás o mesmo erro

Comment: Já testou esse código de criação na sua maquina local?

Comment: sim ele funciona, perfeitamente, mas se passa ele para o mapeamento ou o caminho direto da pasta não funciona, pesquise em alguns lugares e falam que pode ser permissão do usuário apache fazer alteração na rede mas não achei nada que faça essa liberação

Comment: já tive esse problema antes, se o apache estiver rodando como serviço do windows, vá nas propriedades do serviço e defina o usuário que tem acesso na escrita desse diretório remoto.

Comment: Jhonny fiz isso ele esta como serviço sim e esta definido o usuário administrador pra ele, mas mesmo assim nada